# Screen width and height in unity not accurate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a samsung a03 and it's native resolution is 720 x 1600 pixels but when I use Screen width and height in unity it say's 1440 x 648. I also use the Screen.resolutions to check for the supported resolution and it says 720 : 1600. I don't know which is correct the 1440 x 648 or 720 x 1600.

Comment: See https://answers.unity.com/questions/16216/how-to-get-native-screen-resolution.html or https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-screen-resolution-not-window-resolution.319511/

Comment: One answer there mentions using `Display.main.systemWidth`.

Comment: A x B or B x A is more a question of orientation ;) I would suspect the `720 x 1600` from `Screen.resolutions` (which should return multiple values .. it's an array) to be the best possible resolution while `648 x 1440` the currently applied one .. and additionally `1440 x 648` tells us the device/app is in landscape orientation